# Unittest Flask flask.g

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, flask, python-unittest

When I unittest, I want to be able to set and access `flask.g`.

```
flask.g['test'] = {'test': '123'}
test_dict = flask.g['test']
```

produces this error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 346, in __setitem__
    self._get_current_object()[key] = value
TypeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object does not support item assignment
```

However, when I run it in production, everything works. If I use the `setattr` and `getattr`, the unittesting works, but breaks in production, 
I get the following error

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 268, in error_router
    return self.handle_error(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 477, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 587, in dispatch_request
resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
    args = getattr(flask.g, 'test')
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'test'
```

I run the unittest in `app_context()`. The goal is to have unittests that actually represent production. How can I achive this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These two usages are now equivalent

```
user = getattr(flask.g, 'user', None)
user = flask.g.get('user', None)
```

example of usage

```
def get_user():
    user = getattr(g, 'user', None)
    if user is None:
        user = fetch_current_user_from_database()
        g.user = user
    return user
```

more in [official documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/) or [testing documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/testing/)

Comment: It is strange that I can do `flask.g['test'] = 'test'` when running the app (both Flask native runner or gunicorn), everything works fine. But fails in unittest. However, I am using the above code, and everything works.